# Python textinput pop window

Tags: python

I am using Quiz.pyw where questions are written on graphic canvas, answers are entered using:
textiput('Answer', '')
Is there a way to position this pop window?
Thanks

Comment: can you tell me where did you get the Quiz.pyw code

Comment: I wrote it my self. I am adding the whole program to my post:

Comment: File "D:\Python36\quiz.pyw", line 112, in <module>
    root.geometry(20, 20)
NameError: name 'root' is not defined

Comment: you must use the name you used to create the istance of Tk(). I used root = tkinter.Tk() and so I used root.geometry(... if you used a different name instead of root you must use othername.geometry("200x200+100+100"), You have to write the coordinates like that. 200x200 are the sizes of the window, while +100+100 are the positions on the screen.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Hi Mr. Gatto please send your mail id I will mail the code. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position a window you have to (python 3, otherwise do import Tkinter):

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400+200+200")
```

200 200 are the coordinates of the position of the window

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
open python folder and go to Lib/tkinter and find simpledialogue.py.
Edit it using IDLE as:

```
if self.parent is not None:
self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (parent.winfo_rootx()+50,                           
parent.winfo_rooty()+10))
```

change the values 50 and 10 to move it as per your requirement.

Comment: I am not sure about what you did, but I don't think that the proper way to do this is to change a file in the lib... directly... there is for sure a safer way to do it without changing the modules inside the lib... if you make an error you will mess up tkinter... I think... where I should give you my email to see the code ... if you still need it ?

Comment: actually my quiz runs on turtle graphics if i use tkinter another window comes up and text input box (simple dialog box) will always appear relative to that tkinter graphic window, that leaves no choice.

Comment: Ok, so I think you solved the problem this way... it's all good... turtle graphic? Nice...